# Print x86 assembly instead of getting machine code from ExecutionEngine

Tags: llvm-c++-api

I've seen several conflicting descriptions of how to do this around the google results, and haven't been able to get any of them to work.

My problem is basically this: where I call ExecutionEngine::getPointerToFunction (with an llvm::Function*), I'd like to instead get the pretty-printed x86 assembly that would be produced for this function.

Anybody?

[ETA: I'm using LLVM 3.3.  The descriptions I've found seem to be for earlier versions of LLVM.]

Comment: It's helpful to see the code you've tried and how that code has failed, either with the exception or how the result differed from your expectations.

Comment: Nicole, I've edited my comment to make it clear that I'm looking to do this with LLVM 3.3.  The comments I've found on google seem to be for an earlier version of LLVM (since they don't compile with 3.3).

Have you actually done this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that you can add an event listener to a JIT ExecutionEngine with ExecutionEngine::RegisterJITEventListener.  If you provide an instance of that class, you can have your callback invoked when machine code is generated for you, and you'll be given a pointer to the machine code and its length.  With this, you can call llvm::sys::disassembleBuffer to get a description of the machine code buffer.

However, the llvm::sys::disassembleBuffer function just defers to the udis library if LLVM was compiled with that support.  Since my build of LLVM didn't have this flag set and I can't rebuild it, I'll just look into using the udis library directly:

https://github.com/vmt/udis86